# Firebase query on items that are missing on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I have many phrases added with *.push()* to a firebase object like so:

```
phrases: {
  "$phrase_key<1>": {
    text: "Hello",
    language: "eng"
  },
  "$phrase_key<2>": {
    text: "How are you?",
    language: "eng"
  }
  ...
}
```

Each user gets a shot at translating each sentence by language, so I have:

```
translations: {
  portuguese: {
    "$phrase_key": {
      "$user_id<1>": "Oi!",
      "$user_id<2>": "Olá!",  
      "$user_id<3>": "Oi!",  

    },
    "$phrase_key<2>": {
      "$user_id<1>": "Como vai?",
      "$user_id<2>": "Tudo bem?"        
    }
  }
}
```

Im using the $phrase_id before $user_id in hierarchy because, on the front end, I can simply query for a block of phrases the current user hasn't translated yet using

```
var translationsRef = 
  new Firebase("https://<project>.firebaseio.com/translations/portuguese");

var queryRef = translationsRef
  .orderByChild(auth.uid) // Session user id
  .startAt(null)          // Give me phrases the user haven't translated yet
  .limitToFirst(10);      // 10 of them, please
```

This is working fine, except that it is **very slow**, which is understandable since there are tens of thousands of translated phrases and the query is not indexed. Each query takes somewhere between 20-30 seconds to start handing me the results.

I have thought of using *.indexOn* on my current implementation, but it wouldn't work since I'd have to index on every users id, which is just impossible..

I though of using a compound key for translations ($user_id+"_"+$phrase_id) and index on that, but that would only solve the problem of phrases the user have *already translated*. I'd have to add a 'null' to missing translations, (numberOfUsers*numberOfPhrases) times..

Let me know if you guys can find a solution or if I should just hop on elastic search already.

Thanks in advance!

---

#### Answers to Kato's questions

- _Entries that don't exist at all and have zero translations? Entries where a specific user doesn't exist? You aren't using .child($phrase_key) in your query so orderByChild(auth.uid) is never going to match._

Yes, phrases that haven't been translated yet would not show in the query (they are not a key in the object). If they have been translated by anyone (other than the user in the session), they will return. I thought of using the first translation as a way to determine that the sentence is OK to be sent to other translators.

- _You aren't using .child($phrase_key) in your query so orderByChild(auth.uid) is never going to match._

I'm not using $phrase_key because that's what I want to find out. It's like the $dinossaur_species key in the [docs example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries). I made it extra confusing by not separating the ref to be queried from the query itself, like in the docs. Sorry about that.

- *Also, did you want equalTo(null) here? startAt(null) is going to return everything, whether it's null or not?*

Yes, you are right. Changing that.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. Entries that don't exist at all and have zero translations? Entries where a specific user doesn't exist? You aren't using .child(<phrase key>) in your query so orderByChild(auth.uid) is never going to match. Also, did you want equalTo(null) here? startAt(null) is going to return everything, whether it's null or not? This needs some work to clarify the question and goal.

Comment: Sounds like you have a good idea how to handle this now. For others visiting, it's probably possible to solve the $phrase_key bit (assuming this actually is part of the query) by using our [deep path queries](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've been trying to hammer a nail with a slice of pizza (and theres nothing wrong with pizza!). Firebase is amazing but really not meant for this.

Even if I solved the performance issue, there would be two problems unsolvable by firebase

1. In the ideal scenario I would like to randomize the phrases I send to the translator.
2. I was getting back every single translation done on that phrase (of course, it is part of the object structure), when all I needed are the keys for the phrases.

This is a very simple task if you don't have to do it in the front-end, (even elastic search is overkill), I solved the problem by simply using a web app I already have doing other things. I keep an array with the phrases keys and an object with translations in memory (for each language), both in sync with firebase. When the server gets a request with language and user ID, it subtracts the translations done by the user, gets 10 random items and that's it.

Once again, as soon as I explain the problem, the answer jumps in front of me.. Happens so often..

Comment: Nice! Note that if you want to use Firebase for this, then you could probably use a [queue strategy](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) to reduce your web app to a 20-30 line Node script. Firebase makes a great router and API tool (removing auth, security, RESTful services, and more stack complexities from the workers' code).